# CoreData add object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8

I made an app which's using core data. I made a function which saves 1 or 2 values / write data into core data. This is the following method:

```
    func saveName(name: String) {

    let myDate:NSDate = NSDate()
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    if markCell == true {
        newManagedObject.setValue(name, forKey: "markedCell")
        markCell = false
    }

    else {
        newManagedObject.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        newManagedObject.setValue(myDate, forKey: "datum")
    }

    // Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        abort()
    }
}
```

It occurs a crash in the function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if `markCell == true`. If `markCell == false` (step into `else`) all works perfect.

If I run this function:

```
    func saveName(name: String) {

    let myDate:NSDate = NSDate()
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        newManagedObject.setValue(name, forKey: "markedCell")
        markCell = false
        newManagedObject.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        newManagedObject.setValue(myDate, forKey: "datum")

    // Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        abort()
    }
}
```

no crash occurs but than I also added a value to `markedCell`. I only want to add a value into `markedCell` if the bool is set to true (the user pressed a button -> bool will be set to `true` and `func saveName`will be called).

Load data from core data (create UITableViewCell):

```
//Get task
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as  NSManagedObject
    var taskString:NSString
    taskString = object.valueForKey("name") as String
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("name") as? String
    //Set accessory type
    var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"markedCell = %@", taskString)
    var results : [NSManagedObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [NSManagedObject]
    if (results.count > 0) {
        //Element exists
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        println("Cell is marked")
    }
    else {
        //Doesn't exist
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        println("Cell isn't marked")
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the exact message you get upon the crash

Comment: `name` is nil. But is the saving function correct?

Comment: I will check it later at home. Are you sure the passed name variable has a value when the function gets called?

Comment: Can you provide the whole (or all relevant parts) of the project?

Comment: what is your error message? 
Does your object have the key markedCell?

Comment: Could it be that you are not setting 'Datum' when your if statement is true and you are required to set it?

Also I think it's good practise to subclass your NSManagedObject, check this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-subclassing-nsmanagedobject--cms-21880 (this is in obj-C) or http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/07/17/implement-nsmanagedobject-subclass-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

I can bet that the problem comes from the fact that `markedCell` is declared as optional property in your Core Data model while `name` or/and `datum` are not optional.

If this is the case your saving works fine when you enter the `else` loop because at that point you have:

```
markedCell == nil //this is allowed in your Core Data model
name != nil
datum != nil
```

However, when you do not enter into the `else` loop you have:

```
markedCell != nil
name == nil
datum == nil
```

and one of the last two lines is incompatible with your Core Data model. If you want to use your original code you need to ensure that all properties mentioned here are declared as optional.